# Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException trying to upload modified image in Laravel Sail

Tags: linux, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-sail

I am trying to create a command that goes through all images I have in a database and modifies them in some way using the intervention/image package

```
public function handle(): int
{
    $carPartImages = NewCarPartImage::take(20)->get();

    foreach ($carPartImages as $carPartImage) {
        $imageUrl = $carPartImage->original_url;

        // Download the image
        $imageContents = file_get_contents($imageUrl);
        $tempImagePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image');
        file_put_contents($tempImagePath, $imageContents);

        // Load the custom logo
        $logoPath = public_path('img/logo.png');
        $logo = Image::make($logoPath);

        // Load and process the image
        $processedImage = Image::make($tempImagePath);

        // Determine the position to place the logo (top right corner)
        $logoWidth = intval(0.27 * $processedImage->width());
        $logoHeight = intval(0.29 * $processedImage->height());
        $xOffset = $processedImage->width() - $logoWidth;
        $yOffset = 0;

        // Resize the logo to fit the desired dimensions
        $logo->resize($logoWidth, $logoHeight);

        // Replace the region in the image with the logo
        $processedImage->insert($logo, 'top-left', $xOffset, $yOffset);

        // Define the output path and name
        File::makeDirectory('app/public/car-part-images/' . $carPartImage->carPart->id, $mode = 0777, true, true);
        $outputPath = storage_path('app/public/car-part-images/') . $carPartImage->carPart->id;
        $extension = pathinfo($imageUrl, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $outputName = 'image' . $carPartImage->id . '.' . $extension;

        // Save the processed image
        $processedImage->save($outputPath . '/' . $outputName);

        // Update the database with the image name
        $carPartImage->image_name = $outputName;
        $carPartImage->save();

        // Clean up temporary image file
        unlink($tempImagePath);
    }

    $this->info('Image processing completed.');

    return Command::SUCCESS;
}
```

It seems to be able to create the directory fine but when it tries to create the image I get

```
Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException
```

With the message

```
  Can't write image data to path (/var/www/html/storage/app/public/car-part-images/1/image1.jpg)
```

I have tried running all sorts of permission commands in my sail container as root:

```
chmod -R 755 storage
mkdir -p storage/app/public/car-part-images
chown -R www-data:www-data storage/app/public/car-part-images
chmod -R 755 storage/app/public/car-part-image
```

And I added the line

```
            File::makeDirectory('app/public/car-part-images/' . $carPartImage->carPart->id, $mode = 0777, true, true);
```

Hoping that creating the directory before attempting to store the image would be a solution. However nothing seems to work on the existing solutions are here don't seem to be dealing with sail.

Comment: Did you **already** or **not yet** make a symlink with that app/public directory?